# Azure Emulator error: Operation is not supported on this platform

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-compute-emulator

I'm having trouble starting Azure Emulator on my Windows 8.1 laptop. I use Visual Studio 2013. The error I'm getting is:

Windows Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator. Operation is not supported on this platform.

The project I'm trying to build was developed first in VS 2012 so VS 2013 changed some files for me for compatibility reasons.

I tried searching for this issue, but I haven't found any page regarding this error.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem of Azure storage. You may want to check what version of Sql is installed on your laptop. Find this post can be helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/6fafe385-8f1a-4add-b782-3c0761505695/failed-to-initialize-windows-azure-storage-emulator?forum=windowsazuredevelopment